# django queryset aggregate multiple operations fields

Tags: django, group-by, sum, aggregate, django-queryset

model.py

```
class Fatture(models.Model):
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    data =  models.DateField()
    iva  =  models.PositiveIntegerField()
    commissione =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

class Ddts(models.Model):
    fattura = models.ForeignKey('Fatture') 

class DdtsArticoli(models.Model): 
    ddt = models.ForeignKey('Ddts')
    articolo = models.ForeignKey('Articoli')
    quantita = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    prezzo =  models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    colli  =  models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I have to make a query that calculate this total:

1. aggregate table DdtsArticoli SUM(quantita * prezzo)
2. aggregate table DdtsArticoli ((quantita * prezzo) / (1 + (iva of table
   Fatture)/100 ))
3. resut of 1) - result of 2)

Comment: What do you group by? Or you want the total sum of the whole table?

Comment: Whole table not group by

Answer (score 1):

See the [Django docs on aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/) for detail but 1. should be something like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

DdtsArticoli.objects.all().aggregate(
    your_key=Sum(F('quantita') * F('prezzo'), output_field=FloatField()))
```

Number 2. is no aggragation, you can simply calculate it:

```
(obj.quantita * obj.prezzo) / (1 + (obj.ddt.fattura.iva/100.0))
```

Where `obj` is your object aka. your database row.

Number 3. should be trivial then.